# Elasticseach Query Timezone

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, timezone

Hope you all feel well

I have my customers logs in different indexes in elasticsearch with UTC±00:00. On the other side, my customers want queries (absolute time or relative) based on their local timezone. So the result query is based on UTC±00:00 that might not be accurate with that they expect.

what is the best solution to handle this situation ?

Thanks advances.

Comment: You can calculate in UTC timezone and just their local timezone for the frontend. For example, clients enter report ranges in local time and you convert it to UTC and return query results, but when you want to display results, you convert to local time.

Comment: Thank you, Arash for your response. it seems a little bit tricky on the client-side especially when the query size is not small. Also, some queries are group by type that needs to process in the back. For example records per day for customers.

Comment: This method don't add any additional process on your server, since this data should be processed in any timezone. JavaScript just converts the timezone on the client side.